# Operator << in C++, "no operator found which takes right hand-operator" and "already has a body" error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

I have some code that is supposed to overload the operator << and be able to print a matrix object, but for some reason, it fails. Here's the code for it: (Matirx.h file)

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ostream;

template <int N=1, int M=1, class T = int>
class Matrix {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    T matrix[N][M];
public:

Matrix(T matrixVal = 0) :rows(N), cols(M) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            this->matrix[i][j] = matrixVal;
        }
    }
}

int getRows() { return rows; }
int getCols() { return cols; }
T** getMatrix() { return matrix; }

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Matrix<>& mat) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            out << this->matrix[i][j];
            out << " ";
        }
        out << endl;
    }
    return out;
}
```

But when I add it, I get these errors:

> Error C2084   function 'std::ostream &Matrix<4,4,int>::operator <<(std::ostream &,const Matrix<1,1,int> &)' already has a body

> Error C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand
> operand of type 'Matrix<4,4,int>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

> Error (active)    E0349   no operator "<<" matches these operands

here's the main code:

```
#include "matrix.h"

template <int row, int col, typename T>
void printDiag(Matrix<row, col, T>& mat) {
    int number;
    T* diag = mat.getDiag(number);
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
    std::cout << diag[i] << " ";
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
   delete[] diag;
}

int main() {

//freopen("output_matrix.txt", "w", stdout);

Matrix<4, 4> mat;
std::cout << mat << std::endl;

Matrix<4, 4> identity(1);
std::cout << identity << std::endl;
```

any help would be appreciated (:

Comment: And what is the failure?

Comment: `template <int N, int M, class T> friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Matrix<N,M,T>& mat)` rather?

Comment: I tried what you suggested @m88 but it doesn't seem to work,
more errors popped up like  Error C2568 '<': unable to resolve function overload

Comment: @user253751 I updated the question, sorry about that

Comment: @LeonGurin Friend function is not member. You can't use `this`. You don't need the template in this case, but you would want to specify `Matrix<N,M,T>` in the function declaration. Also you can't use `rows`/`cols` use `mat.rows` and `mat.cols`

Comment: Your `operator<<` only takes a `Matrix<>` argument which is short for `Matrix<1,1,int>`. It can't take any other matrix as an argument.

Comment: @Lala5th I implemented your fix and WOW thank you so much! it works like a charm!
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Matrix<N,M,T>& mat) {
  for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < mat.cols; j++) {
    out << mat.matrix[i][j];
    out << " ";
   }
   out << endl;
  }
  return out;
 }
These are the changes I implemented for anyone interested. Again thank you all

Comment: `T** getMatrix() { return matrix; }` looks like a bug.  Does that work?

Comment: @Eljay yes it didn't work for other functions that I needed to create, indeed it was a bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several problems with this. First in the declaration you have to specify the template arguments. As the whole class is templated, you don't need to explicitly add an other `template` before, but you need `Matrix<N,M,T>`.

The second issue is that you treat `friend std::ostream& operator<<(...)` as if it was a member function (using member variables and `this`). This is not the case. You might be declaring it inside the class, but it is definitely not part of the class. Where you use `this->` use `mat.` and where you just use `rows`/`cols` use `mat.rows`/`mat.cols`.

I also had to modify the constructor a bit, but I still don't know why it was complaining.